# Differences between Axis and Allies 1941 and classic edition

Tags: axis-and-allies, edition-comparison

This may seem obvious, but apparently Axis and Allies 1941 has eliminated the construction of factories, and AA guns?

How do these changes affect the play of the game as compared to say, the Classic Edition?

Comment: What problem are you asking us to solve, exactly? (If it has, what about it?)

Comment: @doppelgreener - The questioner is asking for people knowledgable of both games to answer the question.  How does the rule change affect play?

Comment: @Pat That question wasn't there when I left my comment, it was inserted by the answerer below (and not by the question asker, which makes this a wild guess, albeit one that's likely to be correct)

Comment: As demonstrated by your comment on Tom's answer, his "guess" as to what you were really trying to find out was wrong. We shouldn't have to parse your comments on an answer just to determine what question you are really asking. Try asking a real question, plainly and clearly: Was X removed from the game? Why was X removed from the game? When was X removed from the game? What does X cost? What is the combat value of X?

Answer (score 1):

AA guns tend to reduce the value of "strategic" bombing. Hence you would do this more (and spend more researching heavy bombers) than in other versions of the game.

There are many players that believe that [heavy bombers](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3643/in-axis-and-allies-can-heavy-bombers-be-tamed) unbalance the game, and one should not be allowed to research them. If they are disallowed, AA guns would be less necessary, and can be eliminated from the game to simplify it.

The construction of factories is most important for Japan and Britain, who start with only one (everyone else starts with two). Hence, it makes these two countries harder to play.

There are some problems with the [Factory Rule](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3658/should-we-eliminate-or-modify-the-factory-rule-in-axis-and-allies). The first is that one costs a "flat" 15 IPCs to build. But that doesn't reflect the fact that factories are easier to build in some places than others (e.g. in "real life," it's almost impossible to build factory in Sinkiang). Second, most countries would not "export" aerospace technology, meaning that realistically, it would be possible only to produce infantry, but not airplanes in a foreign factory.

Comment: To be frank, it does not seem the question has actually been answered. My game is A&A 1941, a new version. I suppose there are various other versions including "classic." But I am still not totally clear that my game has eliminated AA and factories (which I remember always having in games I played over 15 years ago; much could have changed since then). To me it's a loss (the factories and AA are not in my game, so I assume the are no longer used). These were valuable and fun additions to the game, and I can't understand why they would be removed.

Comment: And in fact, I am thinking of just adding them to my game--and I will need to know how much they cost, what their combat values were, what their other uses were, etc.

Comment: @dpendery: I have expanded my answer to include "issues" I have with "factories," bombers, and AA guns.

Comment: @dpendery http://axisallies.com/rule-books/ has all the details you need. Specifically, IPCs cost 15, can only be placed on territory you owned at the start of turn, units can only be placed on an IPC you owned at the start of your turn, and only 1 unit per income of the territory if not a starting IPC. Given the short number of turns, we found this restriction made them nearly useless.

Comment: AA guns cost 5, are limited to 1 / territory, can move 1 territory per move, and each gun a plane passes over on the way TO but not FROM a bombing run or combat gets a die rolled against it by that gun, a 1 indicates the plane is lost. [Both of these answers are from the 2nd edition, the one I grew up with.)

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that the lack of factory construction and AA guns is a astrisk on the real change of the game, that there are half as many units and a third as much income.  This reduction in units and money makes the game far more luck based than previous editions.  You both have fewer die rolls leading to more deviation from your expected value, and you have very limited ability to replace loses.  The game can easily be decided on the first round due to very good or bad rolling.

I am not saying that the game is not fun, we love it!  But the out-sized effect of the die roll overshadows the lack of factory and AA (which you'll never have the spare cash to build anyway).